# Django Restframework: update an object without accesing specific object id

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-rest-framework

I am using Django with Restframework, and I want to update a certain object. I have the following model:

```
class PromotionalCode(models.Model):
    promotional_code = models.CharField(max_length=10, default=random_with_letters(), unique=True)
    myuser = models.ForeignKey('MyUser', related_name='promotional_code_user', blank=True, null=True)
    promotion_type = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    time_transaction = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())
    used = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

The following viewset:

```
class UpdateOnlyDetailViewSet(mixins.UpdateModelMixin, 
viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    pass
```

The following view:

```
class PromotionalCodeViewSet(UpdateOnlyDetailViewSet):
    queryset = PromotionalCode.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PromotionalCodeSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsOwnerOrReadOnly,)
```

And it has the following url:

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'promotionalcode', views.PromotionalCodeViewSet)
```

I can only update the Promotionalcode object when I access to

> /promotionalcode/code_id

and I want to update a certain code when I access to

> /promotionalcode/

without specifying the id. What I have to do for do it?

Comment: how do you plan on figuring out which object to update without its id?

Comment: Selecting the promotional code that matches the promotional code introduced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found 3 solutions to my problem. I have tested 2 of them:

- First solution: I have created another model called `PromotionalCodesHistory(models.Model)` with the same attributes as `PromotionalCode` and create a serializer with the method create, creating a `PromotionalCodesHistory` instance and call update method to update `PromotionalCode`. Then, when I access to the url `/promotional/` I can update Promotional code.
- Second solution: Modify `DefaultRouter()` to access to update on `/promotional/` url, by the following code:

`from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
class CustomUpdateRouter(DefaultRouter):
        routes = [
            # List route.
            Route(
                url=r'^{prefix}{trailing_slash}$',
                mapping={
                    'get': 'list',
                    'post': 'create',
                    'put': 'update',
                    'patch': 'partial_update',
                },
                name='{basename}-list',
                initkwargs={'suffix': 'List'}
            ),
            # Dynamically generated list routes.
            # Generated using @list_route decorator
            # on methods of the viewset.
            DynamicListRoute(
                url=r'^{prefix}/{methodname}{trailing_slash}$',
                name='{basename}-{methodnamehyphen}',
                initkwargs={}
            ),
            # Detail route.
            Route(
                url=r'^{prefix}/{lookup}{trailing_slash}$',
                mapping={
                    'get': 'retrieve',
                    'delete': 'destroy'
                },
                name='{basename}-detail',
                initkwargs={'suffix': 'Instance'}
            ),
            # Dynamically generated detail routes.
            # Generated using @detail_route decorator on methods of the viewset.
            DynamicDetailRoute(
                url=r'^{prefix}/{lookup}/{methodname}{trailing_slash}$',
                name='{basename}-{methodnamehyphen}',
                initkwargs={}
            ),
        ]`

Then, on view class, reimplement the `get_object` method to specify your own filters to get the object, you can access to `get_serializer_context` method to get context data, the filter is specified using a dictionary of unicode, as the following:

```
{u'key': unicode(variable1), u'key2': unicode(variable2)}
```

- Third solution: Last solution which I have not tested, is to change the primary key to `promotional_code` field, to access promotional code, using `/promotionalcode/promotional_code`